# Cancel form file upload submission

Tags: django, forms, jquery, form-submit

I work on a file upload form with some additional data and want to have a cancel button.

My site is running on Django. I submit the form over the normal way with a submit button without Ajax but I show a progress bar of the upload with jQuery so I enter the submit event with jQuery to show the progress.

Is there a way to cancel this submission with jQuery or some other solution?

I solved this questions here:
[How I can call the browser escape (esc) function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691093/how-i-can-call-the-browser-esc-function)

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How I can call the browser esc function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691093/how-i-can-call-the-browser-esc-function)

Answer (score 0):

As Far as i know Once, the Submit has reached the server there is nothing much you can do with it (the form).

Comment: Why I can cancel with ESC the upload in my Chrome!?

Comment: No, this does the normal Form submission. I wrote only something to show the progress of the file upload.