# How I can call the browser escape (esc) function

Tags: jquery, browser

How I can call this method of the esc function, to stop page loading, with jquery.
This is there some api call or something else.
Anyone an idea?

**EDIT:**

I want to cancel a form submission.

**What I am using now:**

```
window.stop();
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the reason for it? There may be a better way to acheive what you are looking for as the specified behavior will most likely not work in certain browsers on certain os', especially mobile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which== 27) {  // ESC
    window.stop();
  }   
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.stop

> The stop() method is exactly equivalent to clicking the stop button in the browser. Because of the order in which scripts are loaded, the stop() method cannot stop the document in which it is contained from loading, but it will stop the loading of large images, new windows, and other objects whose loading is deferred.

<kbd>**[PLAYGROUND](http://jsbin.com/imedut/1/edit)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a lot works well for me. This was exaclty what I was searching this window.stop() function

Answer (score 2):

Here it is

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) { alert('esc pressed'); }   // esc
});
```

The keyCode property return the key that was pressed so you just need the correct number in your case the Escape key is 27.